# Booting clear linux live image on usb from old non-eufi/efi computer

Tags: boot, uefi, bios, clear-linux

I'm trying to boot Clear Linux live image on my Toshiba Satellite C655 but it does not support UEFI or EFI. I'm using a USB 2.0 64GB thumbstick

[image: partition map]

I wonder if there is a method to boot UEFI partitions from this computer

Comment: @A.B Intel said that `Clear Linux* OS for Intel® Architecture can run on very minimal hardware. For example, it can run on a system with a single core CPU, 128MB of memory, and 600MB of disk space.` so I don't know why they require UEFI at the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: I am not a native English speaker and writing from Android by trying to  remember the exact file, folder and option names, I might enter some names incorrectly

I solved  my problem with Clover

- First I burned the Clover ISO image to blank CD
- After booting the Clover menu is launched with a GUI which has a dragon image on top left and not much option were listed. You have to exit from Clover menu by selecting *exit clover* option, then enter *boot maintenance management*, then *boot from file*, choose the disk Clear Linux is on, choose EFI, then choose the `bootx64.efi` to boot

Comment: you can [install Clover to HDD](https://github.com/m13253/clover-linux-installer) so that you don't need to plug the flash drive or CD in every time